# what is the right way to give @POST for email id and password while using retrofit?

Tags: android, post, retrofit

@POST("api/{email_id}/{pass}")
    Call registration(@Field("email_id") String email_id, @Field("pass") String pass);

i am using in my apiInterface class but not working please suggest me to write right way

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@Path("email_id")` instead of `@Field("email_id")`